# JQuery: consecutive AJAX calls with access to both responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to have two `$.get` methods that runs one after the other, I've looked it up, it seems there are some answers, but all don't mention the ability to access the JSON response.

The first thing I tried was putting a call inside the callback function of the other like this:

```
var url1 = "json_example1.json";
var url2 = "json_example2.json";
var callback1 = function (response1) {$.get(url2,callback2);}
var callback2 = function (response2) {console.log(response1,response2)}
```

The second callback function doesn't even run!

I've also tried using the `when..this` like this

```
var url1 = "json_example1.json";
var url2 = "json_example2.json";
var callback1 = function (response1) {alert("first callback!")}
var callback2 = function (response2) {console.log(response1,response2)}
$.when($.get(url1,callback1)).then($.get(url2,callback2));
```

It throws an error says that response1 is not defined.

even when I put the response inside a global variable like this:

```
var json1,json2;
var url1 = "json_example1.json";
var url2 = "json_example2.json";
var callback1 = function (response1) {json1 = response1};
var callback2 = function (response2) {json2 = response2;console.log(json1,json2)};
$.when($.get(url1,callback1)).then($.get(url2,callback2));
```

for some reason the `callback2` function doesn't get excuted and `json2 = undefined`

so how can I have a consecutive running `$.get` ajax requests with access to both of their response in the second callback function?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a global variable to store data from the first request and then you'll be able to use that data.

```
somefunction = function() {
    var response1;

    $.get('/path_to_somewhere1', function(data) {
        // Store just given response
        response1 = data;

        $.get('/path_to_somewhere2', function(data) {
            alert(response1); // here's response from the first request
            alert(data); // here's response from the second request
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the second file was empty. so now I know that if the second file is empty, the callback function would not get executed.